# What is the current draw of a capacitor in a VOLTAGE BOOSTER

Tags: voltage, capacitor, dc-dc-converter, boost

I'm trying to learn by myself the principles of a voltage boost converter.

[image]

**BATTERY IS 1.2v@4300mAh

I noticed that many sources* suggest not putting a resistor in series with the capacitor (as in the picture).

But doesn't it make an infinite current draw by the capacitor? (R=0)

Thank you.

*for example: http://www.electronoobs.com/eng_circuitos_tut10_1.php
http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva372c/slva372c.pdf

Comment: *But doesn't it make an infinite current draw by the capacitor?* No, why would it? And **if** the capacitor would want to draw as much current as possible, would that current be infinite or would something limit the current?

Answer (score 3):

No way. The choke gets filled when transistor conducts, the current start to rise from 0 to some level. Then you switch off the transistor. What happens with the current? It still flows with the same magnitude for the very first moment, into a capacitor of course, and then starts decaying.

The current through inductor is continuous.

Comment: OK I see, and what if I connect in parallel a load to the capacitor, will the load get all the current while capacitor's charging time?

Comment: @Danaro The load will always get I_load=V_cap/R_load and the rest goes in the cap.